# smallest c s.t. $\int_{0}^1f(x^\frac{1}{n})\ dx \le c\int_0^1 f(x)\ dx $

Tags: calculus, integration

> Let $F=\{f:[0,1]\to[0,\infty)|f \ \mathrm{continuous}\}$ and $n  \ge 2$ (natural). Determine the smallest constant $c$ s.t.
>   $$
> \int_0^1 f\left(x^{1/n}\right)\ dx \le c\int_0^1 f(x)\  dx, \quad \forall f\in F
> $$

I said that $f_p:[0,1]\to[0,1],f_p(x)=x^p$ is in $F$.

So $$\int_{0}^1f \left(x^{p/n}\right)\ dx \le c\int_0^1 x^p\  dx$$
and
$$
\frac{n}{n+p} \le \frac{c}{p+1} \quad p \to \infty \implies c \ge n.
$$

To find if $c \ge n$ I tried to substitute $x^{1/n}=t$ so $$n \int_0^1f(t)t^{n-1}dt \le c \int_0^1f(t)dt,$$ but I don't think this will help. Can somebody give me some tips, please?

Comment: $\int_{0}^1f(x^\frac{1}{n})\ dx = n \int_0^1f(t)t^{n-1}dt \leq  n \int_0^1f(t)dt$ so $c \leq n$

Comment: @Conrad  I don't understand

Comment: I made it an answer since it got too long for a comment to explicit the computations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $0 \leq t \leq 1, n-1 \geq 1$, we have $0 \leq t^{n-1} \leq 1$; now $f(t) \geq 0$ so multiplying we get the inequality $f(t)t^{n-1} \leq f(t)$ on the whole interval $[0,1]$; integrating we get $ \int_0^1f(t)t^{n-1}dt \leq   \int_0^1f(t)dt$, then multiplying by $n$, and using the change of variables that you noted, gives the inequality $\int_{0}^1f(x^\frac{1}{n})\ dx \leq  n \int_0^1f(t)dt$, so if we rename now $t$ as $x$ (change variables again trivially $t=x$) we get $\int_{0}^1f(x^\frac{1}{n})\ dx \leq  n \int_0^1f(x)dx$ which means that $n$ satisfies the required inequality; since $c$ is by definition the least such number, this implies $c \leq n$ and this together with what you did solves the problem

Comment: Thank you! It wasn't so hard at all.

Comment: You almost did it completely, just one extra step needed